# Symmetry factor of a Feynman Diagram

Tags: homework-and-exercises, symmetry, standard-model, feynman-diagrams, higgs

I saw there are already many questions here about the symmetry factor of Feynman diagrams but most of them are about theories that contain only scalars.

My question is: What is the symmetry factor of the Standard Model diagram presented below and why?

[image: Feynman Diagram]

Answer (score 1):

As you probably know, there are various tricks to compute symmetry factors.
Though, a foolproof method is to use Wick`s theorem.

For the diagram at hand the relevant piece from the Lagrangian is

$$\mathcal{L}\supset\tfrac14Z_\alpha Z^\alpha H^2.$$

And the matrix element corresponding to your diagram is (ignoring factors of $i$)

$$\langle0|a_\mu \left(\tfrac14Z_\alpha Z^\alpha H^2\right) a_\nu^\dagger|0\rangle,$$with $a_\mu$ being the $Z$ annihilation operator.

To compute the symmetry factor we need to count the number of contractions. In this case the external legs can contract with the vertex in two ways. To wit, $a_\mu$ can contract with either of the two $Z$ fields in $Z_\alpha Z^\alpha$. The remaining $a_\nu^\dagger$ operator can then only contract with one remaining $Z$, giving a factor of $2$.

There are only two Higgs fields. And the first Higgs field needs to be contracted with the second. This can only be done in one way.

So the symmetry factor is $\tfrac24=\tfrac12$.

Comment: Can you give a better explanation of how many ways the external legs can contract with the vertex? I didn't understand why the Z legs can contract in two ways but the Higgs field can only contract in one.

Comment: What about the diagram with a charged Goldstone boson as internal particle instead of the Higgs? It should have symmetry factor 1, right? But what changes?

Comment: Yes. The thing that changes is how the term in the Lagrangian looks like. If you have n  (same) fields, the term typically comes with 1/n!. Yet the charged Goldstone term involves a field and its conjugate. So no extra 1/2 factor. Insomma, The number of contractions remains 2, but the factor from the Lagrangian is  also 1/2